# Change original port number

Tags: linux, security, port

The default port number for ssh is 22 is there a way to implement security by being obscure and changing the original number? So for example ssh would not be on port 22 it would be on lets say 2847.

Comment: Google is your friend and so is the extensive documentation that comes with your distro of choice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why change default ssh port?](http://serverfault.com/questions/189282/why-change-default-ssh-port)

Comment: Just a note: do read the Wikipedia article that's the first result for "security by being obscure" in Google.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the note, however I don't use google/yahoo/msn but i'll look into that article thanks again

Comment: @TheCleaner I was not aware of that but thanks. Very interesting

Comment: @user180041 Uh... you don't use search engines? Fine, read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: @TheCleaner -_- look into DuckduckGo

Comment: @user180041, you don't need to be obtuse.  'Google it', are 'Google is your friend' are just a  hint **that have done a poor job at research**, not a recommendation for a specific search engine.  This doesn't mean you have to use Google, [use your favorite search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=change+ssh+port+number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most Linux system, the `ssh` port is defined in file :

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

With directive :

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
```

Change port for that directive, let's say :

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 2847
```

And restart `sshd` to apply changes :

```
service ssh restart
```

Now `ssh` should listen on port `2847`